# not show headers in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to get data in output file from sqlplus but it doesn't show me headers. Could anybody help me please? Thanks

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF | egrep -v connected > data.csv
    connect us/pas@sid
set feedback off
set heading on
set wrap off
set pagesize 50000
set linesize 3000
set pages 0
select job from try_table; 
EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line, it should work.

```
set pages 0
```